# Wordpress Gutenberg subscribe not getting updated meta field value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I've been trying to resolve this issue where using the Gutenberg meta box updates, doesn't fetch the new updated meta value.

Meta registration:

```
add_action('init', function() {

    register_meta('post', 'open_unit', array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'single'    => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can('edit_posts');
        }
    ));
    
    register_meta('post', 'open_active', array(
        'type'      => 'boolean',
        'single'    => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can('edit_posts');
        }
    ));

    register_meta('post', 'open_abstract', array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'single'    => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'sanitize_callback' => function($text) {
            return sanitize_text_field($text);
        },
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can('edit_posts');
        }
    ));
});
```

Enqueue assets:

```
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', function() {

    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->post_type === 'page') return;
    
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'open-panel',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/admin.js',
        array('wp-i18n', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-components', 'wp-data', 'wp-plugins', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-api-fetch'),
        filemtime(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/js/admin.js')
    );
});
```

Javascript:

```
const el = element.createElement;

    const { Fragment } = element;
    const { registerPlugin } = plugins;
    const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = editPost;
    const { TextareaControl, ToggleControl, Text } = components;
    const { withSelect, withDispatch, subscribe, registerStore } = data;

    const ActiveCheckboxControl = compose.compose(
        withDispatch(function(dispatch, props) {
            return {
                setMetaValue: function(metaValue) {
                    dispatch('core/editor').editPost(
                        //{ meta: { [props.metaKey]: (openValidate && metaValue) } }
                        { meta: { [props.metaKey]: metaValue } }
                    );
                }
            }
        }),
        withSelect(function(select, props) {
            return {
                metaValue: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')[props.metaKey],
            }
        }))(function(props) {
            return el(ToggleControl, {
                label: props.title,
                checked: props.metaValue,
                onChange: function(content) {
                    props.setMetaValue(content);
                },
            });
        }
    );


    const AbstractTextControl = compose.compose(
        withDispatch(function(dispatch, props) {
            return {
                setMetaValue: function(metaValue) {
                    dispatch('core/editor').editPost(
                        { meta: { [props.metaKey]: metaValue } }
                    );
                }
            }
        }),
        withSelect(function(select, props) {
            return {
                metaValue: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')[props.metaKey],
            }
        }))(function(props) {
            return el(TextareaControl, {
                label: props.title,
                value: props.metaValue,
                onChange: function(content) {
                    props.setMetaValue(content);
                }
            });
        }
    );


    registerPlugin('open', {
        render: function() {
            return el(Fragment, {},
                el(PluginDocumentSettingPanel,
                    {
                        name: 'open',
                        title: 'Open'
                    },
                    // Active
                    el(ActiveCheckboxControl,
                        {
                            metaKey: 'open_active',
                            title : 'Show'
                        }
                    ),
                    // Abstract
                    el(AbstractTextControl,
                        {
                            metaKey: 'open_abstract',
                            title : 'Abstract'
                        }
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    });

...

let isSavingChecked = true;
    let editor = data.select('core/editor');
    const getOpenUnit = () => editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta') ? editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta').open_unit : null;
    const getOpenActive = () => editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta') ? editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta').open_active : false;
    const getOpenAbstract = () => editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta') ? editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta').open_abstract : null;
    let openUnit = getOpenUnit();
    let openActive = getOpenActive();
    let openAbstract = getOpenAbstract();
    console.log(openUnit);
    const unsubscribe = subscribe( _.debounce( () => {

        const isSavingPost = editor.isSavingPost();
        const newOpenUnit = getOpenUnit();
        const newOpenActive = getOpenActive();
        const newOpenAbstract = getOpenActive();

        if (isSavingPost) {
            isSavingChecked = false;
        } else {
            if(!isSavingChecked) {
                let post = editor.getCurrentPost();

                let data = {
                    active: openActive ? 'active':'paused',
                    abstract: post.meta.open_abstract,
                    wp_id: post.id,
                    wp_title: post.title,
                    wp_url: post.link,
                    wp_image: post.featured_media
                }

                let openValidation = openValidate(data);

                if (openValidation.valid) {
                    if(openActive !== newOpenActive || openAbstract !== newOpenAbstract || openUnit !== newOpenUnit) {
                        openRemote(data);
                    } else {
                        console.log(newOpenUnit); //This field is not returning the updated meta field from Wordpress
                        openRemoteUpdate(data);
                    }

                } else {
                    wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').removeNotice('OPEN_NOTICE');
                    wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createNotice(
                        'warning',
                        openValidation.messages.join(', '),
                        { id: 'OPEN_NOTICE', isDismissible: true }
                    );
                }
                isSavingChecked = true;
                openActive = newOpenActive;
                openAbstract = newOpenAbstract;
                openUnit = newOpenUnit;
            }
        }
    }));
```

I am basically trying to fetch the updated meta field:
`const getOpenUnit = () => editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta') ? editor.getEditedPostAttribute('meta').open_unit : null;`

But it's currently looking like this in the console where it's null(`console.log(openUnit)`) or empty(`console.log(newOpenUnit)`)  https://share.getcloudapp.com/E0uYKWGv Lines 195 & 224

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I have found to get and set meta is using `useEntityProp()` in a function component. It is a lot easier to reason about than using `withSelect` and `withDispatch`.

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import { useEntityProp } from '@wordpress/core-data';
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';

export default function MetaComponent(props) {
    const postType = useSelect((select) => {
        return select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType();
    });

    const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', postType, 'meta');

    return (
        <TextControl
            label={ __('Meta', 'pb') }
            value={ meta.open_abstract ? meta.open_abstract : '' }
            onChange={ (value) => setMeta({open_abstract: value}) }
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: This helped but it was another hook that I was using that I needed to switch i.e. `publish_post` to `wp_after_insert_post `